# Can native English speakers tell the differences between [ɣ] voiced velar fricative and [g] voiced velar stop?

Tags: pronunciation

We don't have [g] in Vietnamese so I use [ɣ] instead. I wonder if it is acceptable since I can't tell the difference between them. And it seems like that native speakers can't distinguish the voiceless pair, because I saw people use [k] voiceless velar stop for [x]voiceless velar fricative when pronouncing foreign words.

Comment: I have no idea what you wrote, and I have to research on it. Maybe you shouldn't even care when most of us don't.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an audio or video file(s) demonstrating these two different sounds?  It's very hard to say whether i can tell the difference between two things using just my imagination.

Comment: http://sail.usc.edu/span/rtmri_ipa/je_2015.html

Comment: This is the link where they demonstrate all the IPA sounds. I cant find any real life example though. But I think people from Liverpool do have the voiced velar fricative sound

Comment: In my native tongue the sound /ɣ/ is much more common than /g/, and I can tell you they are different sounds. Native English speakers may not tell the difference if they hear the sound, but they will tell there's something off with your accent. Similarly, a lot of Spanish speakers pronounce the sound /ʃ/ closer to a Polish /ɕ/. Again, native speakers won't be able to tell them apart but they will feel there's something wrong. My advice is that you work on the sound /g/. Pronounce a /k/ and try to voice it. You'll get yourself understood if you pronounce a /ɣ/ instead but you'll sound odd.

Comment: Yes, @ZoDoj, Liverpool speech has both [x] and [ɣ], and speakers in the rest of England would recognize them as variants of [k] and [g].

Comment: My advice would be to record yourself saying "Give me a bag of angry tigers", then find a friend whose native language is also Vietnamese but claims to be able to pronounce [g] correctly and have them record the same sentence. Then the native English speakers here can comment on whether the g sounds are clearer in one of the recordings.

Comment: People will often recognise ɣ as a variant of g, but it could also be a variant of an r-sound (which has a wide range of articulations especially in non-native speakers), or maybe even other letters. Generally people will be able to get it by context, but not all the time, especially with unfamiliar words or names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First rule of English is that nobody in their right mind care about phonetics.
- Second is that mistakes are a part of life, and overly clear, especially well articulated and grammar immaculate sentences are used by NNEs - as strange as that may sound.

So, if you can pass that however you pronounce it, and don't get really bad stares, it's all good. Carry on.

Comment: Yes, English is quite tolerant of pronunciation differences.  You should of course attempt to achieve the best pronunciation you can, but don't be anxious about minor issues.

Comment: There's this tolerance level, that if circled around, gets minor stares but is fine. Then there's below the level, which is instant warning bells that someone doesn't know how to speak English. Anything above that level is fine. Striving for the best, but as with anything - and Especially being parents - good enough is okay.

Answer (score 0):

A fair amount of English speakers would be able to hear the difference, but many would understand you if you replaced velar stops with velar fricatives.